# Why I can see this transaction data of the first block?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

I don't think there is anyone moved Genesis Block. But when I check it with blockchain.com, why I can see one transaction?

[image]

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the coinbase transaction of the genesis block, as the screenshot says. It pays the reward for mining that block (50 BTC) to that address (owned by the miner of the first block, assumed to be Satoshi Nakamoto). It pays *to* the address, but has not been touched since (and in fact, the genesis block reward is technically unable to be spent even if Satoshi wanted to spend it).